# XSSF. NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

```
private void cleaner(Integer columnsCount, Integer rowsCount, Object object){
    int firstColumn=0;
    int firstRow=0;
    XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (int lineId=firstRow;lineId<rowsCount;lineId++)   {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(lineId);
        for (int columnId=firstColumn;columnId<columnsCount;columnId++){
            row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(object.toString());  }
    }
}
```

I really do not understand this logic. Firstly, i get row and then I'm trying write the data. I certainly know that, all my data are not null.
But compiler says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at workhere.WriterXlsx.cleaner(WriterXlsx.java:75)
    at workhere.WriterXlsx.<init>(WriterXlsx.java:19)
    at workhere.Start.main(Start.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

WriterXlsx.java:75 : `row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(object.toString());`

I start this method with : `cleaner(30,30,"");`

Comment: I bet `row.createCell` or `.setCellValue` throws NPE so object is NULL. Can you check that with debuger or sysout that object?

Comment: and? i already know that problem at 75 string, what next?

Comment: I believe `sheet.getRow(lineId);` returns `null`.

Comment: @kocko impossible, What should I do? Use Iterator?

Comment: Is it impossible because you have checked it or because you say so?

Comment: @Antoniossss because i have only one row at this moment, but it will be larger

Comment: Ok, but I dont see that you are creating it anywhere, thats why i am asking. Just sysout `row` after getting it just to be 101% sure please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to clean a row if it exist, why don't check if the row is not null?

Try this:

```
private void cleaner(Integer columnsCount, Integer rowsCount, Object object){
    XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (int lineId=0; lineId < rowsCount; lineId++)   {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(lineId);
        if(row != null)
            for (int columnId=0; columnId < columnsCount; columnId++)
                row.createCell(columnId).setCellValue(object.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow%28int%29)

```
sheet.getRow(lineId);
```

returns null if row doesn't exist. You need to [create](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createRow%28int%29) a row before accessing it in case row does not exists (or skip it).

Comment: if i use createRow for this row, it will be deleted. How I understand it removed or not?

Comment: What do you mean? why would it be deleted?

Comment: when we use createRow it will create a new row of empty cells
If you worked  with this API you should know this aspect.

Comment: we use getRow for getting data and createRow for writing

Comment: But what if you try to get a row that does not exist? In that case you **must** create it.

Comment: BTW my answer states that you create only if getRow returns null, so you dont delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is : Use `Iterator` and leave alone the World :)
Why @whoAmi isn't right? Because i don't know exist this row or not. `Iterator` helped me.

Comment: damn, i used my second accout(